# how to handle warnings shown when applying flyway migrations on MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, flyway, utf8mb4

After upgrading to MySQL 8.0 I started testing flyway migrations that I have been using on our current MySQL 5.7, I started seeing warning about deprecation like

```
WARNING: DB: Integer display width is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
WARNING: DB: 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous. (SQL State: HY000 - Error Code: 3719)
```

Now I understand why those warning are shown and I understand that some queries needs to be modified but I am not sure how to fix them because I can not change the sql migrations since it will cause checksum failure on production and when applying to an existing database.

What is the correct path forward regarding those warnings?

Didn't find any flyway documentation about upgrading to 8.0 and what needs to be done.

Comment: are you using the latest flyway version?